# Creating a Counter Column Comparing Column Values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, counter

I am trying to create a counter for a dataset using managers  and their employees below is a sample of what I have:

```
Employee_ID     Manager_ID 
     1              5
     2              5
     3              5
     4              7
     5              7
     6              7
     7              14
     8              9
     9              7 
    10              9
    11              12
```

And this is what I want:

```
  Employee_ID       Manager_ID       Employee_Count
       1                5                   3
       2                5                   3
       3                5                   3
       4                7                   4
       5                7                   4
       6                7                   4
       7                14                  1
       8                9                   2
       9                7                   4
       10               9                   2
       11               12                  1
```

so far my code looks like this

```
count = 0 
reports = []
for i, column in df.iterrows():
    if column['Employee_ID'] == column['Manager_ID']:
         count += 1
         reports.append(count) 
    else:
         reports.append(0)
df['Employee_Count'] = reports
```

If I run this I get all 0s, I am assuming this is because it is running row by row. But I am just guessing.
*I updated the table to a more accurate visual. I apologize for the change.*

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataFrame.transform` which allows you to use `groupby` operations without modifying the index.

Transform `Manager_ID`s to their counts:

```
df['Employee_Count'] = df.groupby('Manager_ID').transform('count')
```

---

```
   Employee_ID  Manager_ID  Employee_Count
0            1           5               3
1            2           5               3
2            3           5               3
3            4           7               2
4            6           7               2
5            8           9               2
6           10           9               2
7           11          12               1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code your asking whether the Employee ID is equal to the manager ID, which looking at your dataframe it never is, therefore you always get 0.
But comparing IDs isn't what you were trying to achieve. You're just interested in the occurrence of each manager ID, and adding those as an extra column. Indexing is easiest:

```
manager_count_list = [(df['Manager_ID'] == manager).sum() for manager in df['Manager_ID']]
df['Employee_Count'] = manager_count_list
```